# CSS - Why is Border not Working?

Tags: css, wordpress, border, padding

I am currently coding a Wordpress website. I have a sidebar and the main body for my blog posts. The sidebar currently has the following properties:

```
.nav{
width:25%;
height: 100%;
background: #FFF;
display:block;
float:left;
position:relative;
border-right:thin solid #C8C8C8;
}
```

and the main body for blog posts:

```
body {
font-family: Myriad Pro, Tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
margin-left:20%;
margin-right:20%;
}

.post {
padding-left:10px;  
border-left:thin solid #000000;
}
```

I am currently trying to add padding-left to .post so that there is a gap between the right border of the sidebar and the blog posts. However, this is not working (a gap is not created) for some reason. Nor is border-left (there is no border created; I tried removing the border-right property on the sidebar).

This is currently the code for index.php

```
   <div id="blog">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class = "sidebar">    
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I make padding-left and border-left work for the main blog posts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a link to where this is being used so we can better analyze the environment it's in?

Comment: i am still locally developing this in XAMPP..... perhaps I can send/post the files here so u can take a look at them? if so what files do u want?

Answer (score 1):

Padding is applied within the element, so the border is on the *other* side of the padding. What you need is margin, which is applied outside of the element:

```
.post {
    margin-left:10px;  
    border-left:thin solid #000000;
}
```

[Here is an article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/05/mastering-css-coding-getting-started/#CSS-Basics1) explaining padding and margin in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a conflict between the default Wordpress CSS and your themes CSS file(s). A quick hack is to add `!important` to the end of the CSS declarations as follows:

```
.post {
  padding-left: 10px !important;  
  border-left: thin solid #000000 !important;
}
```

A long-term solution is to examine what CSS files are loaded (and in what order) and what selectors are being used. Excellent resource: http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS_Troubleshooting

Comment: i tried adding !important and is not working (it gives me the exact same results as without !important)... do you have another solution for this?

Comment: That would be easier if you linked to the site.  The only way to really tell is by seeing the site as a whole.

Comment: i am still locally developing this in XAMPP..... perhaps I can send/post the files here so u can take a look at them? if so what files do u want?